# How to I combine ClearCase config spec element selections

Tags: clearcase

Is it possible to combine the following two configspec lines in one?

Original configspec:

```
element .../test_dir_A/... .../my_branch/LATEST
element .../test_dir_B/... .../my_branch/LATEST
```

To something like

```
element .../[test_dir_A or test_dir_B]/... .../my_branch/LATEST
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regex in general aren't supported for config spec path.

The [man page about config_spec](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm) confirms the use of **pattern**, so maybe something like:

```
element .../test_dir*/... .../my_branch/LATEST
```

could work (even though it wouldn't be restrict to just A or B)

The [wildcard man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/wildcards_ccase.htm) lists all the possibilities:

```
element .../test_dir_[AB]/... .../my_branch/LATEST
```

should be what you want.

```
[xyz]
```

> Matches any of the listed characters.

Comment: Sorry, I made little too easy for the example, I really meant there are totally two different directory strings in stead of just A and B difference. (i.e .../the_first_dir/... and ../second_dir/...)

Comment: @cpeng: that is why I mentioned the *absence* of regex support: in that case, you cannot mix two different paths on the same selection rule.